# A Conformal map onto unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let $U=\{x+iy, x<0, 0<y<\pi\}$. Map $U$ conformally to the unit disk.

My instructor gives me a hint that first I should consider the image of $U$ under the map $\cos z$. I guess that then $U$ is mapped to the upper half plane but I cannot show that. Can you give me a hint?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\cos$ is the composition of $e^{iz}$ with $(z+1/z)/2$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more?